# Timeout when docker build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am learning docker, I am trying to deploy a node app, here is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

when running :

```
docker build .
```

I have the following issue :

```
Step 1/7 : FROM node:8
Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/node/manifests/8: Get https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fnode%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: dial tcp: lookup auth.docker.io on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:55428->127.0.0.53:53: i/o timeout
```

Could someone help me please ?

Comment: I checked that I can't neither do a docker login or a docker pull..

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, it was solved after login, then I could run build command succesfully.The credentials should be the same as those from Docker Hub repository (https://hub.docker.com).

```
docker login
```